# Backbone.js Persisting child variables to parent

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, hierarchy

What is the correct way to persist an inherited variable, on action to the parent in Backbone.js?
I can see some logical ways to do this but they seem inefficient and thought it might be worth asking for another opinion.

The two classes are both views which construct a new model to be saved to a collection, the parent passing a variable through to a popup window where this variable can be set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure there's enough detail in your question to answer, but there are a few ways to to do this:

- **Share a common model.** As you describe it, you're using two views to construct a model, so the easiest way is probably to pass the model itself to the child view and have the child view modify the model, rather than passing any variables between views:

  ```
  var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

  var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
      // initialize the new model
      initialize: function() {
          this.model = new MyModel();
      },

      // open the pop-up on click
      events: {
          'click #open_popup': 'openPopUp'
      },

      openPopUp: function() {
          // pass the model
          new PopUpView({ model: this.model })
      }
  });

  var PopUpView = Backbone.View.extend({
      events: {
          'change input#someProperty': 'changeProperty'
      },

      changeProperty: function() {
          var value = $('input#someProperty').val();
          this.model.set({ someProperty : value });
      }
  });
  ```
- **Trigger an event on the parent.** If for some reason you can't just pass the value via the model, you can just pass a reference to the parent and trigger an event:

  ```
  var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize: function() {
          // bind callback to event
          this.on('updateProperty', this.updateProperty, this);
      },

      updateProperty: function(value) {
          // do whatever you need to do with the value here
      },

      // open the pop-up on click
      events: {
          'click #open_popup': 'openPopUp'
      },

      openPopUp: function() {
          // pass the model
          new PopUpView({ parent: this })
      }
  });

  var PopUpView = Backbone.View.extend({
      events: {
          'change input#someProperty': 'changeProperty'
      },

      changeProperty: function() {
          var value = $('input#someProperty').val();
          this.options.parent.trigger('updateProperty', value);
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: Perfect, the event triggering was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad this helped. Note that the first option (passing the model) will also trigger an event (the "change:someProperty" event on the model), and in my opinion might be more straightforward.